# How to block script which is changing content of index page

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a project it have one index file and 40+ 'JS' files if I change the content like in div, heading, paragraph, etc in index file due to some script it remains same as old and not showing the change when I open in live server so I am expecting that is there any way like if I change any tag in index page then if a script is trying to change the content of any particular tag then it will block it

Explained above

Comment: This question needs more details, like fore example a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, what have you tried? can't you just modify the script that alters your elements?

Comment: Object.defineProperty(document,{
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: false,
    writable: false,
  });

Comment: please edit the question itself using the "edit" link instead if you want to add information. Also your syntax for [defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) is wrong, missing the property name (you configure a property of an object, not the object itself). And my intuition tells that it won't work as document is not really a property

Comment: oh i thought that full document it will select so any other preferred solution ?

Comment: I would need more details, as your question looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me (maybe there's a simpler solution than what you ask specifically). I doubt this would work but you can still try: `Object.defineProperty(window, 'document', { enumerable: false, configurable: false, writable: false, });` because as I see `document` seems to be a property of `window`